# pandas: operating between rows after grouping and reindexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with several 1000 rows that look like this:

```
 x.head()
         id                       jname  wbdqueue_id       startdatetime  \
59  1341127   ondemand_build_baspen-w7g        26581 2017-07-31 23:14:56
60  1341126      ondemand_qa_qforchecka        26581 2017-07-31 23:15:35
61  1341125      ondemand_build_bchecka        26581 2017-07-31 23:14:56
63  1341123   ondemand_build_baspen-w7f        26581 2017-07-31 23:10:05
64  1341122  ondemand_update_waspen-w7a        26581 2017-07-31 23:09:32

           enddatetime
59 2017-07-31 23:19:12
60 2017-07-31 23:34:12
61 2017-07-31 23:15:30
63 2017-07-31 23:14:56
64 2017-07-31 23:10:00
```

I would like to, for each wbdqueue_id, get the difference between *startdatetime* of ondemand_update_waspen-w7a and *enddatetime* of ondemand_build_baspen-w7g. What is the way to do it?

I imorted the CSV file and parsed both *startdatetime* and *enddatetime* as time. I then grouped by wbdqueue_id. My thought was to index each group by *jname* so that I can find the start and end timestamps for the two *jname* I need.
But when I do that all other values become NaN or NaT (for the time columns).

-Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a function with the described logic to make things very explicit and the subsequent code easy to follow:

```
import pandas as pd


def get_time_diff(dff):
    start_time = dff[dff.jname.eq('ondemand_update_waspen-w7a')].startdatetime.values[0]
    end_time = dff[dff.jname.eq('ondemand_build_baspen-w7g')].enddatetime.values[0]
    return pd.Timedelta(end_time - start_time)
```

Then you can use the function in a `group-by` operation:

```
df.groupby('wbdqueue_id').apply(get_time_diff)
```

This yields:

```
wbdqueue_id
26581   00:09:40
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Please note that I am going with `end_time - start_time`, because logically you would want to return a positive time delta and end times are always greater than start times.

I hope this serves a purpose.

Comment: While PiRSquared's proposal is succint, I agree this is more flexible. I've already hit an issue with data cleanup (some groups don't have either or both of those _jname_). I am still trying to figure out how to cleanup / drop group after groupby if data is missing and a function for groupby seems to be a logical way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
df.set_index('jname').groupby('wbdqueue_id').apply(
    lambda x: x.at['ondemand_update_waspen-w7a', 'startdatetime'] \
            - x.at['ondemand_build_baspen-w7f', 'enddatetime']
)

wbdqueue_id
26581   -1 days +23:54:36
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This is beautiful

Comment: I was thinking the same as @Bharathshetty ! But I think, you also could add the method using `diff`, just in case further learners had a similar problem but with more than two different values in the column `jname`.

Comment: Thank you to you both.  `diff` would be useful when two values are a predictable distance away from one another.  I don't have that luxury here because I have one column of one row and another column in another row where I have no assurances of there relative positions.  I could force the issue, but I think it turns ugly very quickly.  Also, in this case, I have to assume that `jname` is unique per `wbdqueue_id`.  If it wasn't I'd have to make choices in regards to which one I'd choose.  If you have a specific idea in mind, post a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the different between statrdatetime and enddatetime in your result, you can try this .

```
df1=df.loc[df.jname.isin(['ondemand_update_waspen-w7a','ondemand_build_baspen-w7f']),:]
df1.groupby('wbdqueue_id').apply(lambda x:x.startdatetime-x.enddatetime.shift())[4]


Out[467]: 
wbdqueue_id
26581.0   -1 days +23:55:00
Name: 4, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```